# How do I install the Odoo 10 enterprise modules on the community version?

Tags: odoo

I'm searching for the high-level approach. I understand that this questions can be explained platform specific, so that is not what I ask specificaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highest level approach that you can get is this:

Put all the enterprise modules in a folder and put that folder in your `addons_path` *before* the community addons. That means `addons-path=/path/to/enterprise/addons,/path/to/community/`

Keep in mind:

1) Before doing anything ***absolutely*** backup your existing database.

2) When you have the enterprise modules in place and the `addons-path` correctly set up, kill ***all*** instances of the server and then run the server with `-d your_database_name -u all`, so that everything will be loaded properly.